# Flex stretched menubar items

Tags: apache-flex, layout, menubar

I am using a MenuBar in Flex:

```
<mx:MenuBar labelField="@label"
        width="100%"
        cornerRadius="0">
...
</mx:MenuBar>
```

By specifying the width as 100% the menu bar stretches across the entire container as desired, but I would also like the items inside to stretch to their maximum possible width instead of simply aligning to the left side.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into creating a custom ItemRenderer for your menu. I haven't played with a MenuBar at all, but in a quick lookover I see that it has a menuBarItemRenderer property. You may need to create your own renderer to have it do what you're looking for. Don't forget to implement the correct interfaces and override the data setting functions if you choose to go this route (should be easy to find tutorials online)

Answer (score 0):

When you add items to the menu bar, you can also set their width to 100%. This gives the desired effect for me; alternatively, place the items in a HGroup with 100% width to override the menubar formatting.

Comment: I'm using a `MenuBar` with a `dataProvider` using an `XMLList`. I can't seem to find the proper place where to set the width or add the `HGroup`.

Comment: If its the label field that is being displayed can you not set the label width properties to suit?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Flex, but I can't seem to find where to adjust the label width properties. Perhaps somewhere in css, or in as3? I'm still using solely MXML at the moment.